# Volcar datos de una SELECT a un objeto en SQL Developer

Tags: base-de-datos, select, objeto, inicializacion, oracle-21c

Tengo creados tres objetos en Oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Tableta AS OBJECT (
num_serie VARCHAR2(20),
estado VARCHAR2(14),
marca VARCHAR2(10),
fecha_asignacion DATE,

CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION Tableta(
    c_num_serie VARCHAR2,
    c_estado VARCHAR2,
    c_marca VARCHAR2,
    c_fecha_asignacion DATE)
RETURN SELF AS RESULT,

CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION Tableta(
    p_num_serie IN VARCHAR2, 
    p_marca IN VARCHAR2)

    RETURN SELF AS RESULT
```

)
FINAL
INSTANTIABLE;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Usuario AS OBJECT(

cod_usuario INTEGER(4),
tipo VARCHAR2(12),
nombre VARCHAR2(10),
apellidos VARCHAR2(30),
correo_elect VARCHAR2(40),

CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION Usuario(
    c_cod_usuario INTEGER,
    c_tipo VARCHAR2,
    c_nombre VARCHAR2,
    c_apellidos VARCHAR2,
    c_correo_elect VARCHAR2)
    
RETURN SELF AS RESULT
```

)
FINAL
INSTANTIABLE;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Prestamo AS OBJECT(

numero INTEGER(4),
usuario_asignado Usuario,
tableta_asignada Tableta,
fecha_asignacion DATE,
fecha_fin_asignacion DATE
```

)
FINAL
INSTANTIABLE;

También una tabla de cada uno de los objetos

Tengo que crear un procedimiento para que añada un objeto Prestamo en la tabla Prestamos

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ALTA_PRESTAMO (serie VARCHAR2, c_user INTEGER) IS

tableta1 TABLETA := NEW Tableta(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
usuario1 USUARIO := NEW Usuario(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
numero NUMBER :=0;
```

BEGIN
SELECT num_serie, estado, marca, fecha_asignacion
INTO tableta1
FROM TABLETAS
WHERE NUM_SERIE='123456789aaa';

```
SELECT cod_usuario, tipo, nombre, apellidos, correo_elect
INTO usuario1
FROM USUARIOS
WHERE USUARIOS.COD_USUARIO=1000;

SELECT (MAX(NUMERO)+1) INTO NUMERO FROM PRESTAMOS;

INSERT INTO PRESTAMOS VALUES (numero,usuario1,tableta1, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), '24/06/2023');

UPDATE TABLETAS SET TABLETAS.ESTADO='Asignada' WHERE NUM_SERIE=SERIE;
```

END;

Al ejcutarlo me da este error

```
Procedure ALTA_PRESTAMO compilado
```

LINE/COL  ERROR

---

10/5      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
12/5      PL/SQL: ORA-00947: no hay suficientes valores
16/5      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
18/5      PL/SQL: ORA-00947: no hay suficientes valores
Errores: comprobar log de compilador

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.